# If statement within function doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
func endRound() {
    timerLabel.isHidden = true
    var label1Index = allEvents.index(of: label1.text!)
    var label2Index = allEvents.index(of: label2.text!)
    var label3Index = allEvents.index(of: label3.text!)
    var label4Index = allEvents.index(of: label4.text!)
    if (label4Index > label3Index > label2Index > label1Index) {
        score = score + 1
        let successImage = UIImage(named: "next_round_success")! as UIImage
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.setImage(successImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        round = round + 1
    } else {
        let failImage = UIImage(named: "next_round_fail")! as UIImage
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.setImage(failImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        round = round + 1
    }
    if (round == 6) {
    }
}
```

For some reason, I recieve a:

> "Value of type 'Array.Index?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '??'"

error next to the first `if` statement.

When I add `!` marks, as the compiler suggests, next to each variables within the `if` statement, I recieve a:

> "Binary Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'Array.Index' (aka int)"

and:

> "Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence'"

Not sure what to do. The variables within the `if` statement represent the index number of the strings of the labels (just read the code and you would understand this).

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: I think your title is truncated

Comment: What do you want your program to do if one or more of the search strings is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues. The call to `allEvents.index(of: label1.text!)` returns an optional result since it is possible that text won't be found in the array. Adding the `!` runs the risk of your app crashing if the text isn't found. One option would be to set a special value such as `-1` in such a case.

```
var label1Index = allEvents.index(of: label1.text!) ?? -1
var label2Index = allEvents.index(of: label2.text!) ?? -1
var label3Index = allEvents.index(of: label3.text!) ?? -1
var label4Index = allEvents.index(of: label4.text!) ?? -1
```

Now for the `if` statement. You can't chain a bunch of `>` comparisons like that. You need:

```
if (label4Index > label3Index && label3Index > label2Index && label2Index > label1Index) {
}
```

Comment: Good answer, although converting an empty optional to -1 seems to defeat the purpose of optionals (not using some "magic value" to represent a "no valid result found" or empty state. It would be better to use optional binding, guard statements, or some other code to cleanly handle the case where the strings aren't found.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, you make a valid point. I only suggested using the "magic number" of `-1` in this case because it seemed to be a simple way to achieve the goal here. It would probably be a good idea for you to post an answer showing how to do it as you suggest.

Comment: rmaddy, it isn't clear to me what the OP wants to do if one or more of the strings is not found.

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy says in his answer, you are getting a message about your indexes not being unwrapped because the string `index(of:)` function returns an Optional, which will be nil if the string isn't found.

As rmaddy also pointed out, your code to makes sure the strings are in the correct order is also invalid.

The code `if a > b > c > d` is not valid Swift. You have to rewrite that as

`if a > b && b > c && c > d`

Assuming that failing to find any of the strings means you want to follow the fail path, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
func endRound() {
    var scored = false
    timerLabel.isHidden = true
    if let label1Index = allEvents.index(of: label1.text!), 
      let label2Index = allEvents.index(of: label2.text!),
      let label3Index = allEvents.index(of: label3.text!),
      let label4Index = allEvents.index(of: label4.text!),
      label1Index > label2Index && 
      label2Index > label3Index && 
      label3Index > label4Index {
        score = score + 1
        let successImage = UIImage(named: "next_round_success")! as UIImage
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.setImage(successImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        round = round + 1
    } else {
        let failImage = UIImage(named: "next_round_fail")! as UIImage
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.setImage(failImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        nextRoundButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        round = round + 1
    }
    if (round == 6) {
    }
}
```

That code should increase the score if all 4 strings are found and in the correct order. If one or more of the strings are not found, or anything is not in label1 label2 label3 label4 order, it will execute the else (fail) clause.

I **think** that's what you're after...